# How to get started with SQLCipher for Hybrid App?

Tags: angularjs, sqlite, ionic-framework, sqlcipher

I need to use SQLCipher for Hybrid Android. I have already made my app using **ionic** with **SQLite** database & just want to convert it into **SQLCipher**.

I am new to sqlcipher.

I have read about it in this link: https://www.zetetic.net/sqlcipher/

But, still I'm not too clear. If you could provide some basics regarding sqlcipher will be useful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The easier way to use sqlcipher would be to find a Cordova plugin that is working with it.

There seems to be a plugin that is made for that :
https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlcipher-adapter

But it doesn't seem to be very stable. I hope it helps.

Comment: I have add the github using,
  git clone https://github.com/sqlcipher/sqlcipher.git
further what I have to do for encript my sqlite database?

Comment: You can see here the documentation here : https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlcipher-adapter#opening-a-database. That's not this repository that you need to clone but the cordova plugin. You simply need to do : `cordova plugin add https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlcipher-adapter` if you have cordova installed.